# Passing a float between 0 and 1 to NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
float beat = 1/2;
    NSLog(@"timeinterval: %f",beat);
```

"timeinterval" keeps turning up 0

Is there something wrong with my xcode? Or have I just been sitting here too long and missing something obvious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the result of integer division in C (which is what objc is based on). To fix, explicitly use floating point values:

```
float beat = 1.0 / 2.0;
NSLog(@"%f", beat); // works correctly.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float x = 1.0/2.0;
NSLog(@"The Float Number is %f",x);
```

This is how you will the value of `x` in float.